# How to use ValidateAntiForgeryToken in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to use ValidateAntiForgeryToken for cross site forgery. I haven't been able to make this work with ExtJs. I have a custom session token, but I need a page request token.

I tried variations of the following for a replacement of @Html.AntiForgeryToken():

xtype: 'hidden',
id: '__RequestVerificationToken',
name: '__RequestVerificationToken',
value: '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()

This is not syntactically correct.